# When is content updated?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Let's say I would like to change the text of an element, during some long function in a script:

```
// Inside test.aspx.cs
void SomeLongFunction_CalledOnClick()
{
    this.idOfElement.Text = "something";
}
```

When, precisely, is the client sent information about this update? Can I force it to happen earlier?

Comment: Add a breakpoint and learn when it is done, Have a look at the Page Lifecycle for more info.

Comment: It doesn't matter when the event is called as the whole page will be reloaded (or part of it will if you are using ajax) and the result will be rendered to the browser.

Comment: I could identify when it would be done with a breakpoint, but I was looking more conceptually -- page lifecycle info is exactly what I needed.

Comment: These blogs are a bit old, but they should help: http://devarchive.net/displaying_progress_bar_for_long_running_processes.aspx
http://blog.devarchive.net/2008/01/calling-page-methods-from-javascript-by.html

Comment: Based on your comments you should search for http://www.bing.com/search?q=asp.net+report+progress+long+running - there are multiple ways to do so from long poll to web sockets, (i.e. check out SignalR).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using web forms, the content of the browser is updated when the "Render" stage of the page life cycle runs. Generally the code in a web form's code behind runs before the render stage.

[Here is a link that explains the page lifecycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472(v=vs.85).aspx)

I'm afraid that if you are looking to update the UI to indicate progress, the web forms model isn't made to work that way. All the content is sent to the browser as a single unit during the render phase.

If you want your UI to show progress you could poll for updates using ajax calls, or use a technology like SignalR (although it's probably overkill for your use case).

Comment: This is incorrect, the client won't see anything until the request completes and the response is sent back to the client. There is no simple way to both force the client to see the information earlier and still run your long running task (assuming you also want to display the result of the task)

Comment: We have a loading screen we would like to make dynamic, to see what's running during a long task. This seems impossible then?

Comment: Not impossible, just difficult :)

Comment: Matt, everything you say is correct, but I don't see how that conflicts with my answer

Comment: @Aheho, looking closer it doesn't really. The way the answer is phrased, I thought you were saying that the browser content is updated constantly during the render stage. You may want to add that all updates to the page are sent to the client together in a single response during the render stage, so there is no way to send incremental updates using the page lifecycle.